# употребление форм слова "собрание/собранье"

Tags: грамматика

в каких случаях можно употреблять слово собранье а в каких собрание

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, это одно слово.
Во-вторых. Современные правила допускают употребление формы "собранье" и подобных слов только в поэтической и разговорной речи.
В-третьих, я не согласен с Tagirix и его источником, что форма "собранье" - старое написание. Как раз раньше (до реформы 17-го г.) подобные вольности допускались куда реже. Там просто надо смотреть, какие слова раньше получили подобную редукцию. Но общий процесс шел имнено в таком направлении - от полной формы -ие (в старой орфографии -iе, начиная едва ли не со времен братьев солунских) к современным разговорным формам -ье.

Answer (score 1):

Согласной [этой странице](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%B5), слово ***собранье*** — это старое написание слова ***собрание***, что, в принципе, логично. Вообще, ***ье*** практически всегда указывает на старое написание в подобных словах, но есть и такие случая, когда оно выполняет другую функцию, например: варение (процесс от глагола ***варить***) и варенье (результат этого процесса, то есть сама пища).